# issue with button in html bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm following this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36jRXMsIFuA
I am using bootstrap 5.0.0 beta 1
My code is following:

```
    <header>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12 bg-light">
              <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn border dropdown-toggle my-md-4 my-2" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false">AUD</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">USD</a>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-12 text-center bg-dark"></div>
            <h2 class="my-md-3 site-title">Online Store</h2>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-12 text-right bg-danger">
              <p class="my-md-4 header-links">
                <a href="#" class="px-2">Sign In</a>
                <a href="#" class="px-1">Create an Account</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

And it looks like this, and when I click the button there is no dropdown. Layout is messed up as well.
[my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sePMc.jpg)

Compared to tutorial:
[tutorial picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn950.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial's using **Bootstrap 4.3.1**, the 4th version rather than the newest **5.0**. If you switch to v4, your dropdown would works. Since a major update of a framework (increase of the first version number) is always not compatible to below versions.

About the layout, there's a mistake in your code. You need to put your `<h2>` tag ***within** the tag with a background color and a style*, the above `<div>` tag.

So, change the lines below:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-12 text-center bg-dark"></div>
<h2 class="my-md-3 site-title">Online Store</h2>
```

To:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-12 text-center bg-dark">
  <h2 class="my-md-3 site-title">Online Store</h2>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12 bg-light">
        <div class="btn-group">
              <button class="btn border dropdown-toggle my-md-4 my-2" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false">AUD</button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">USD</a>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-12 text-center bg-dark">
        <h2 class="my-md-3 site-title">Online Store</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-12 text-right bg-danger">
        <p class="my-md-4 header-links">
          <a href="#" class="px-2">Sign In</a>
          <a href="#" class="px-1">Create an Account</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: BTW my suggestion if you'd like to learn the newest version of Bootstrap: **1.** Also learn the difference between two versions, and rewrite the different part of code. **2.** Just drop that video tutorial and follow the [Official tutorial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) to build a site of your own, it's not so hard, and you can learn much more by working on it.